# Showing that a function has a certain absolute minimum.

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have the function $$f(x) = \frac{x}{p} + \frac{b}{q} - x^{\frac{1}{p}}b^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ where $x,b \geq 0 \land p,q > 1 \land \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$

I am trying to show that $b$ is the absolute minimum of $f$.

I proceeded as follows:

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{x^{\frac{1}{p}-1}}{p} b^{\frac{1}{q}} = \frac{x - x^{\frac{1}{p}} b^{\frac{1}{q}}}{px}$$

Now I will look for critical points by searching for the zeros of this function.

$$\frac{x - x^{\frac{1}{p}} b^{\frac{1}{q}}}{px} = 0 \iff x - x^{\frac{1}{p}} b^{\frac{1}{q}} = 0 \iff x = x^{\frac{1}{p}} b^{\frac{1}{q}}$$.

Now I can see that $b$ is a critical point.

How ever when I continue my calculations to check whether there are any other critical points
$$x = x^{\frac{1}{p}} b^{\frac{1}{q}} \implies x^p = b^{\frac{p}{q}}x \implies x^{p-1} = b^{\frac{p}{q}} \implies x = b^{\frac{p}{(p-1)q}}$$

But this could not be equal to $b$, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\dfrac{p}{q(p-1)}=1$$ since $\dfrac1p + \dfrac1q = 1$. This is because, we have $\dfrac1q = 1 - \dfrac1p = \dfrac{p-1}p \implies \dfrac{p}{q(p-1)} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks man, I have been looking for this for ages.

Comment: Just to make sure, now that I know that the only critical point is b, and since one point to the left of $b$ is larger than 0 and a single point to the right of $b$ is larger than 0, we get that $f$ reaches an absolute minimum in $b$ right?

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of the [Weighted Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality). It uses the concavity of $\log(x)$ and can be generalized to
$$
\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha_i}\le\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i\tag{1}
$$
where $\alpha_i\ge0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$.

$(1)$ follows from [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) because $\log(x)$ is concave. Just exponentiate the following instance of Jensen
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\log(x_i)\le\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i\right)\tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let  $\dfrac{1}{p}=a$ and $\dfrac{1}{q}=k$

$ax+bk-x^a \cdot b^k=f(x)  $

$\dfrac{x + \dots x_{ath}+ b+ \dots b_{kth}}{a+k} \ge (x^ab^k)^{1/(a+k)}$ (By [AM-GM inequality)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

$x+ \dots x (a$ times)$=ax$ and $b+ \dots b (k$ times)$=bk$

$a+k=1 \implies ax+bk \ge x^a\cdot b^k \implies ax+bk-x^ab^k \ge 0$

Now you have $f(x) \ge 0$, the minimum is achieved when $x=b$ and $a=k$